# ATL Conversion Macro Doesn't like being in it's own function

Tags: string, visual-c++, atl

I am using the ATL conversion macro A2T to convert between std::string and const TCHAR*.  I then feed the TCHAR* to an additional function for parsing of a file.  When I do the following, it works:

```
USES_CONVERSION;
const TCHAR* fileName = A2T(file.c_str());
foo(filename);
```

However, I tried to refactor out the empty checks, and conversion using a new function:

```
const TCHAR* StringToTChar(const string s)
{   
/*  To be added in
      if(s.empty())
      {
          return NULL;
      }
*/
      USES_CONVERSION;
      const TCHAR *ts= A2T(s.c_str());//Using ATL, convert to TCHAR*
//  assert(ts!=NULL); to be added

    return ts;
}
```

Now the function foo(filename) says it can't open the file I give it.  I can only assume this is because the filename variable is formatted incorrectly.  Is there anything wrong with this code?

Thanks,

Eric

EDIT:
It looks like the input string is "C:\abc\build\Dvv\ggg.trc" and the string foo receives is "C:\abc\buivv\ggg"

Comment: This is explained in [ATL and MFC String Conversion Macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3(v=VS.80).aspx). Specifically, in the table of ATL 3.0 macro behavior, it says "The string is freed when the function is exited."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`A2T` macro converts the string using stack memory space. The pointer `ts` is valid until return from the function and the data pointed to by it get damaged then.

If you change return type to `ATL::CString`, you will be fine from there.